# Where can I create a custom figure?

Tags: minifigures, customization

So while it is nerdy, I want to create the Call of Duty: Zombies characters out of LEGO in real life to play with or model. But I can't find any sites where I can create them. Can someone help?

Comment: Welcome to our site! I hate to tell you this, but this is probably a duplicate of another question, and might be closed. So, in the future, just make sure to check and see if the topic is already covered here.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Minifigs.me](http://minifigs.me)! It allows for creation using almost every part, plus custom parts.

Also try BrickLink, which has a catalogue of nearly every LEGO piece in existence. (For sale!)